# Segmentation fault while erasing vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

```
while(!v1.empty() || !v2.empty())
{
    int k=0;        
    if(v1[k] < v2[k])
        v1.erase(v1.begin());
    else
        v2.erase(v2.begin());
    cout<<v1[0];
}
```

this is my code 
here i want to  remove the elements till one of them is empty(vectors are sorted) ,
like if

> v1 contains 2,3,5,8
>
> v2 contains 3,4,7

then according to me it should give me  `8` but its giving `segmentation fault`

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger?

Comment: So while `v1` isn't empty OR `v2` isn't empty, you want to delete something from one of them? What if that one is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(!v1.empty() && !v2.empty())
{
    int k=0;        
    if(v1[k] < v2[k])
        v1.erase(v1.begin());
    else
        v2.erase(v2.begin());
}
if (!v1.empty()) {
    cout << v1[0];
} else if (!v2.empty()) {
    cout << v2[0];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use && instead of ||:

```
while( !v1.empty() && !v2.empty())
```

Without that you are entering the while loop when one of the vectors is empty, and subsequently trying to access an element that isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&`:

```
while( !v1.empty() && !v2.empty())
{
    ...
}
```

The second fall is that you use `v1[0]` after `erase`. If `erase` deletes last element of the vector `v1` then `v1[0]` leads to undefined behavior.

```
if(v1[0] < v2[0])
    v1.erase(v1.begin());
else
    v2.erase(v2.begin());
cout << v1[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below condition:

```
if(v1[k] < v2[k])
```

This condition doesn't check, if a `vector` is already empty or not. If one of the `vector`s gets emptied then you are accessing an forbidden location (either `v1[0]` or `v2[0]`). So your condition should be like:

```
while(!(v1.empty() || v2.empty()))
```